# How can I stream different audio to multiple Discord servers at once?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently working on 24/7 radio function in my bot but i just cant get it right...
What I am stuck on is on debugging because how it turns out, the audio that is getting from the radio station is played on all connections, and I want to make different radio stations running at different servers.

Here's the code:
(link is defined)

```js
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 0.3, fec: true, bitrate: 320, highWaterMark: 24 }
const broadcast = message.client.voice.createBroadcast();
broadcast.play(link, streamOptions);
for (const connection of message.client.voice.connections.values()) {
    connection.play(broadcast);
}
voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
    message.client.voice.broadcasts.forEach(broadcast => {
        connection.play(broadcast, streamOptions);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Nope, but already fixed that, but thanks for trying

Comment: And what's wrong exactly?

Comment: I posted an answer, I just used the broadcast which is in itself function to make it globally (thats how i understand it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I finally figured out my solution.
Changed snippet:

```js
voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
    connection.play('https://rs101-krk.rmfstream.pl/RMFFM48', { volume: 0.3});
});
```